# postNotificationName si not being called?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, presentmodalviewcontroller

Hello everyone `postNotificationName` is not being called in the following situation: I have a `viewcontrollerA` when i click on a button the user must login. So I do a `presentmodal` for the login. And just before presenting the modal I add the Notification. After the user has logged in the I call `postNotificationName`  and then dismiss the modal. But the observer is never called. Also I notice if I dont dismiss the modal the observer is called. Any help ?

Comment: It probably has to do with the timing of when you're adding the observer, but you need to post your code for us to know. Are you sending these notifications between viewControllerA and this modal controller?

Comment: hello thanks for your reply. I am registering / adding  the notification on viewControllerA and after I call this [[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loggedin" object:nil]; in the modalViewController. @rdelmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably too late to add the notification, because that modal controller is being deallocated. In any case, you really shouldn't be using a notification for this purpose. You can either use a delegate, or you can pass the information back directly to viewControllerA. From the modal view controller you can use self.presentingViewController to get a pointer to viewControllerA. You could have a BOOL property in ViewControllerA (lets call it isLoggedIn) and just set its value from the modal view controller just before you dismiss it.

```
self.presentingViewController.isLoggedIn = YES;
```